# What is the code meant?

Tags: javascript

I want to remove the cookie from the site. Somebody told me to use this code. But I do not know the functionality of the code. Please tell me.

***Here ref is the cookie name which is generating in the site.***

```js
var referrer = document.referrer; //returns the URL of the document that loaded the current document.
if (referrer.indexOf(location.host) == -1) {
  console.log('1');
  jQuery.removeCookie('ref');
  if (jQuery.cookie('ref') === undefined) {
    jQuery.cookie('ref', referrer, {
      expires: .5,
      path: '/'
    });
    referrer = jQuery.cookie('ref');
    console.log('2');
  } else {
    console.log('3');
    jQuery.removeCookie('ref');
    referrer = jQuery.cookie('ref');
  }
} else {
  console.log('4');
  referrer = jQuery.cookie('ref');
}
```

Comment: You should search for what each functions does. SO is for helping in solving a problem. You should not be asking for explaining algorithms. I'll have to flag this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a user to your website, say:

```
http://example.com/
```

Now, the `document.referrer` is `""` (blank) as it was not "referred" by any link. The user typed it. The `document.referrer` holds the link from which the page has been opened.

Now, when the home page has a link like http://example.com/signup, and the user clicks it, and goes to the page, and the page has the following code:

```
document.referrer; // This would give http://example.com/ as the referrer.
```

When you are checking this:

```
referrer.indexOf(location.host) == -1
```

What exactly happens is:

```
"http://example.com/".indexOf("http://example.com/") == -1
```

Where, both have the content. This shows that the link has been clicked from the local page available in the same domain. When the referrer is not the local page, then add the referrer in the cookie and do some process is what the `if` condition does.

There are a lot of conditions in the code. They are the cases from where the user might have come from.

**Case 1:** User has not come from anywhere. It returns `undefined`. You will get `2` logged in the console.

**Case 2:** If he comes from a different page, You will get `3` logged in the console.

**Case 3:** If he comes from the same page, You will get `4` logged in the console.